# how to create custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` and Im trying to set a `label` and an `image` in the `collectionViewCell`. Unfortunately I cant seem to get any labels to display or anything else for that matter.

Here is my code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *issue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,cell.bounds.size.width,40)];
    if(indexPath.item %2 == 0){
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        issue.text = @"Some Text";
        issue.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        issue.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        issue.text = @"Some Text";
        issue.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        issue.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately no label is being displayed and neither is the text in the label.

**Updated**: I've added the rest of the code from this class file.

```
#import "ContainerListController.h"
#import "ContainerController.h"
#import "ContainerList.h"


@implementation ContainerListController


//Deallocate temp variables
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

//Initiate objects
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super initWithTitle:LocStr(@"CONTAINER_LIST_TITLE") navBarHidden:NO]) {
        m_paths = [ContainerList shared].paths;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(onContainerListDidChange)
            name:kSDKLauncherContainerListDidChange object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

//Load all the views.
- (void)loadView {
    //Allocate a UI view
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];

    //Create flow layout
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    //Force Horizontal Scroll
    [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing =[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing=0.0;


    //Create Collection
    UICollectionView *coll =[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];

    //Allocations
    m_coll = coll;
    coll.dataSource =self;
    coll.delegate =self;
    coll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    coll.collectionViewLayout = layout;

    //Customize Cells
    [coll registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [coll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    [layout invalidateLayout];

    //Create the subview
    [self.view addSubview:coll];




    //set minimum spacing
    /*if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
        NSLog(@"Changed to landscape Spacing");
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 100.0f;
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 100.0f;
    }
    else{

        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 40.0f;
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 40.0f;
    }*/

    //Old Layout
    //UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    //m_table = table;
    //table.dataSource = self;
    //table.delegate = self;
    //[self.view addSubview:table];

}

- (void)onContainerListDidChange {
    m_paths = [ContainerList shared].paths;
    [m_table reloadData];
    [m_coll reloadData];
}

//Debugging components function
/*-(void)printComps:(NSArray* ) components{
    for (NSInteger i =0; i<16; i++) {
        NSString * item;
        item=components[i];
    }
}*/

//old tableview cell
- (UITableViewCell *)
    tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
        reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    NSString *path = [m_paths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *components = path.pathComponents;
    cell.textLabel.text = (components == nil || components.count == 0) ?
        @"" : components.lastObject;
    return cell;
}

//Old tableView
- (void)
    tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSString *path = [m_paths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ContainerController *c = [[ContainerController alloc] initWithPath:path];

    if (c != nil) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
    }
    NSLog(@"Selected an item");
}

//old TableView count for epubs
- (NSInteger)
    tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return m_paths.count;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    //m_table.frame = self.view.bounds;
    m_coll.frame = self.view.bounds;
}

//Collection View Cell Data Allocation
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *issue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,cell.bounds.size.width,40)];
    //UICollectionViewCell *content = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init];
    if(indexPath.item %2 == 0){
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        issue.text = @"Some Text";
        issue.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        issue.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        issue.text = @"Some Text";
        issue.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        issue.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    NSString *path = [m_paths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *components = path.pathComponents;
    NSString *Title = components.lastObject;

    NSLog(@"Title: %@",Title);
    NSString *Titletest = components.lastObject;
     NSInteger comp1 = components.count;
     NSString *comps = @"components";
     NSLog(@"There are: %ld %@", (long)comp1,comps);
     NSLog(@"Title: %@",Titletest);
     for (NSInteger i =0; i<15; i++) {
     NSString * item;
     item=components[i];
     NSLog(@"Component:%ld %@",(long)i,components[i]);
     }

    return cell;
}

//Collection View Cell Data De-Allocation
- (void)
collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
numberofItemsInSection:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSString *path = [m_paths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ContainerController *c = [[ContainerController alloc] initWithPath:path];

    if(c !=nil){
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
    }
}

//Collection
-(NSInteger)
    collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return m_paths.count;
}


//Set Collection View Cell Size
-(CGSize)
    collectionView:(UICollectionView *) collectionView
    layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    //Set Landscape size of cells
    /*if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
        CGFloat cellWidth =  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-360;
        CGFloat cellHeigt = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-60;
        NSLog(@"Is Landscape");
        return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeigt);
    }
    //Set Potrait size of cells
    else{
        CGFloat cellWidth =  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-60;
        CGFloat cellHeigt = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-160;
        NSLog(@"Is Portrait");
        return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeigt);
    }*/

    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, collectionView.bounds.size.height);
}

//Collection View Cell Position
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
         return UIEdgeInsetsMake(150.0,0.0,150.0,0.0);  // top, left, bottom, right
     }
     else{
         return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);  // top, left, bottom, right
     }
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{

    [m_coll performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator{

    [m_coll performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
}

/*-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)
collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{

    CGFloat cellSpacing = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *) collectionViewLayout).minimumLineSpacing;
    CGFloat cellWidth = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *) collectionViewLayout).itemSize.width;
    NSInteger cellCount = [collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];
    CGFloat inset = (collectionView.bounds.size.width - ((cellCount-1) * (cellWidth + cellSpacing))) * 0.5;
    inset = MAX(inset, 0.0);

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){

        NSLog(@"Changed to landscape Spacing");
        return inset;

    }
    else{

        return inset;
    }

}*/
@end
```

Comment: you need to create custom class and use instead of `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: So the `UICollectionViewCell` custom class contains the label details and any other objects?

Comment: by creating custom class you can maintain ui components by referring them `cell.yourLabel.text = @"some value"` and other objects which are pre declared.

Comment: So just so you know im an idiot. Is this how its done?`UICollectionViewCell *content = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init];` then i just refer content in the CollectionViewCell

Comment: okay, what you need now some more help example regarding your issue ?

Comment: Yes, like I said I am an idiot. How do i get the labels. All I did was init it in `loadView()`

Comment: I think just init a collectionview cell isnt enough. I think i need to create a class with a labels and images etc

Comment: check my ans and let me know if still doubt.

Comment: where are you adding the label as subview ? Please show the complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear example to use custom `collectionViewCell`.

Create a separate class subclass of`UICollectionViewCell` see below code:

**.h file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *customLabel;
@end
```

**.m file:**

```
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation CollectionViewCell

@end
```

Now drag and drop the `collectionView` inside `viewController` using `storyboard` then by selecting cell set custom class for it and connect its `IBOutlet` of label see below image.

**Setting up custom class:**

[image]

**Connecting label's outlet:** *if adding label and other ui component from storyboard*

[image]

Note: Drag `uilabel` inside cell before you connect its `IBOutlet`.

---

Now configure cell inside your `viewController` class. And configure `collectionView` correctly by connecting its `delegate`, `dataSuorce` and `IBOutlet`.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    // instance variable deceleration part 
    NSMutableArray *yourArray;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _yourCollView.delegate = self;
    _yourCollView.dataSource = self;

    yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1st cell",@"2nd cell",@"3rd cell",@"4th cell", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

// collection view delegate methods
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [yourArray count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // configuring cell
    // cell.customLabel.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // comment this line if you do not want add label from storyboard 

    // if you need to add label and other ui component programmatically 
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height)];
    label.tag = 200;
    label.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // this adds the label inside cell
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    return cell;
}

//Note: Above two "numberOfItemsInSection" & "cellForItemAtIndexPath" methods are required.

// this method overrides the changes you have made to inc or dec the size of cell using storyboard.
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:   (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}

}  // class ends
```

Setup the cell identifier (by selecting a cell) `MyCustomCell` you have given inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method before use see below image:

[image]

**Note: Change the text color of `uilabel` to white before because by default `collectionView` appears black.**

Hope here you understand.

Comment: When I try and create a new `UICollectionViewCell` i get a duplication error. I also cant add the `UILabel` to my .h file

Comment: Let me give some few hours.I'll update the answer asap.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate it

Comment: @ZaydBhyat now try hard and respect my time please thanks.

Comment: nice I can see you put a lot of effort in. Good job.. However, I cant use storyboards. I need to generate the labels etc programatically

Comment: @ZaydBhyat again updated my ans please see, adding label programmatically is just need to change few lines inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Hope now you will get complete idea.

Comment: Ok I think i understand, I have to create a seperate class file with a .h and .m for UICollectionViewCell and that class can contain all the objects that need to be part of the cell. Correct?

Comment: Thanks I will get on this after lunch and i will let you know how I go.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. For instance `TestCollectionViewCell`.
2. In `Storyboard` drag `label` in cell and set `"Custom class"` for this `UICollectionViewCell` with your created class. Set `Reusable identifier`, if your collection view in `UIViewController` don't forget to set `DataSource` and `Delegate` for that `collectionView`.
3. Connect `IBOutlet` in your Cell subclass.
4. Set at least 1 value inside `numberOfItemsInSection` method.
5. Then use your subclass of cell in `cellForItemAt` and try set text for a label.

Comment: I need to create it programatically due to the nature of a third party framework that collects the data. So i cant use storyboards

Comment: Do same stuff but without IBOutlets and init views in awakeFromNib

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the:

```
  [cell.contentView addSubview:issue];
```