# Multiple Section in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I was building an iOS app for my hospital using collection view. However, I need to use multiple sections for the specialist clinic depends on the purpose. I already completed the code if it's just for 1 section. when I try to make it 2 sections, it always returns a nil value.

please check my code below

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        var buttonSpecialist = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton

        buttonSpecialist.setTitle(list[indexPath.row].SpecialtyName, for: .normal)

        let btnimg = try? UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: URL(string: list[indexPath.row].ImageUrl)!))

        var newimg = imageResize(image: btnimg as! UIImage, scaledTo: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

        buttonSpecialist.setImage(newimg, for: .normal)
        buttonSpecialist.contentMode = .center
        buttonSpecialist.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        //let sign: Int = imageOnTop ? 1 : -1
        let imageSize: CGSize? = buttonSpecialist.imageView?.frame.size
        buttonSpecialist.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(((imageSize?.height)! + 5) * 1, -(imageSize?.width)!, 0, 0)
        let titleSize: CGSize? = buttonSpecialist.titleLabel?.bounds.size
        buttonSpecialist.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-((titleSize?.height)! + 5) * 1, 0, 0, -(titleSize?.width)!)

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
    else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        var buttonSpecialist = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton

        buttonSpecialist.setTitle(list2[indexPath.row].SpecialtyName, for: .normal)

        let btnimg = try? UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: URL(string: list2[indexPath.row].ImageUrl)!))

        var newimg = imageResize(image: btnimg as! UIImage, scaledTo: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

        buttonSpecialist.setImage(newimg, for: .normal)
        buttonSpecialist.contentMode = .center
        buttonSpecialist.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        //let sign: Int = imageOnTop ? 1 : -1
        let imageSize: CGSize? = buttonSpecialist.imageView?.frame.size
        buttonSpecialist.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(((imageSize?.height)! + 5) * 1, -(imageSize?.width)!, 0, 0)
        let titleSize: CGSize? = buttonSpecialist.titleLabel?.bounds.size
        buttonSpecialist.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-((titleSize?.height)! + 5) * 1, 0, 0, -(titleSize?.width)!)

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
```

The main problem here is, I didn't know how to set the specific cell for the specific section. I already using 'IF' inside the function 'cellforindexpath', but it didn't worked.

this is my return number of items in section

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 2
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items

    if section == 0 {
        return list.count
    }
        else if section == 1{
            return list2.count
        }

    return 0

}
```

please help me

Comment: add numberofSection method .

Comment: What is the value you return in the method numberOfSections(in:)? Are you sure the code segment for the condition "indexPath.section == 1" is actually executed?

Comment: @christ2702 are you getting the cell as nil ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Make sure assigning DataSource & Delegate to CollectionView

1.Give number of sections you wanna show using below method

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

2.Set item count of each sections for CollectionView using below method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return (section == 0) ? list.count : list2.count
}
```

3.Assigning cell for each item to CollectionView.

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    //If you are using multiple cells based on section make condition 

     if indexPath.section == 0 {
             //make sure the identifier of your cell for first section
             let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
            // do your stuffs
             return cell
     }else{
             //make sure the identifier of your cell for second section
             let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)
            // do your stuffs
             return cell
      }

}
```

Comment: I want the same cell but, the content inside the cell was different

Comment: @christ2702 then simply put              let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
 at the top method.

Comment: 1 more question. how to add section header in each section?

Comment: please check my another problem too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614743/add-uicollectionview-in-uicollectionviewcell/44618023#44618023

Answer (score 0):

If you have different cells layout requirement in that case you should use different custom cells with different reuse identifier. As I can see in your code you have same layout of cell with different datasource.

So I would say try to subclass the collectionview cell and put a IBOutlet property for button through xib or storyboard in the subclass.

You can refer this question:
[how to create custom UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633613/how-to-create-custom-uicollectionviewcell)