# Correctly create uicollection view in iOS using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I've been trying to get a collection view working properly in iOS.
I've been following this question:
[how to create custom UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633613/how-to-create-custom-uicollectionviewcell)

I think I have most of it correct, I'm using the tutorials custom cell class exactly (see the link for the code for that) but I keep running into an error when I access the view controller with the collection view.

Here is my code:

```
#import "BackPackController.h"
#import "UICollectionViewCell+CollectionViewCell.h"

@interface BackPackController () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

@end

@implementation BackPackController

NSArray *itemArray; //our item array

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    itemArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"PlayerItems"]; //get the players items from the user defaults and make an array of them
    _itemGrid.delegate = self;
    _itemGrid.dataSource = self;
    //[_itemGrid setDataSource:self];
    //[_itemGrid registerClass:CollectionViewCell.self forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell1"];

}


- (nonnull __kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Got this far");
    CollectionViewCell *cell1 = [_itemGrid dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell1.customLabel setText:itemArray[indexPath.row]];
    return cell1;
    
}



- (NSInteger)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    return itemArray.count;
    
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:   (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}
```

I have correctly attached the controller as delegate and data source as far as I know. the NSLog in the code above does print its message so I know that cellForItemAtIndexPath method is being called. However as soon as it is called I am getting this error back and I am struggling to understand exactly what is causing it:

```
2023-11-16 08:36:19.163928+1300 Matoran Quest[7698:1793467] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:], UICollectionView.m:3389
2023-11-16 08:36:19.164525+1300 Matoran Quest[7698:1793467] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the collection view's data source returned nil from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: for index path <NSIndexPath: 0x8db3e297ef8cf73e> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'
```

The list that is being accessed is a simple list of strings and I know that it is functioning correctly as I am accessing it elsewhere without problems. I've tried changing the text being added to the cell to just @"test" but this changes nothing

Comment: did you check if `cell1` is null in the cellForItem method ?

Comment: Is _itemGrid attached to its IBOutlet? I've noticed that you're dequeuing a cell using ivar: CollectionViewCell *cell1 = [_itemGrid dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath]; , and usually it is done by referring the collectionView param from delegate method like: CollectionViewCell *cell1 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWith... If your collection has dataSource set in NIB, but it's not attached to itemGrid outlet, your "number of cells" will return correct count, but dequeuing from nil collection will result to nil cell

Comment: You commented out the line for registering the cell class with the collection view. You need that line.

Comment: when I don't have it commented out it fails with a symbols error

Comment: I couldn't attach the grid to iboutlet as it wouldn't let me. I've now gone and made it just a regular variable. Can you please answer this question with how you would set it out programmatically Mykyta iOS?

Comment: ok, worked out the problem. I couldn't attach the collectionview as an outlet because I had attached  a search bar to the controller and whenever I tried to attach it it kept trying to attach to the search bar and so wouldn't show up the collection view. solved that bug. However now I'm getting this: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier cell1 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' but my storyboard does contain a prototype cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, worked out why this was happening and its kind of dumb. I had a search bar attached to my collection view and I couldn't correctly allocate the view as an outlet because whenever I dragged my viewcontroller to my collectionview it kept trying to attach to the search bar instead of the collection view. of course I didn't have an outlet for the search bar so it kept showing up at nothing to attach and as a result because it wasn't attached the code wasn't working properly. I removed the search bar and attached it correctly then it worked fine. Thanks for the help though guys.

Answer (score 2):

Start simple...

Use the following code:

---

**UICollectionViewCell+CollectionViewCell.h** - *note: not sure why you named your file like that... generally, a "Class+Name" is used for a **Category** ... but, assuming the code in the class looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *customLabel;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**UICollectionViewCell+CollectionViewCell.m**

```
#import "UICollectionViewCell+CollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation CollectionViewCell

@end
```

---

**BackPackController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface BackPackController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *itemGrid;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**BackPackController.m**

```
#import "BackPackController.h"
#import "UICollectionViewCell+CollectionViewCell.h"

@interface BackPackController () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

@end

@implementation BackPackController

NSMutableArray *itemArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    itemArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    
    // let's generate a simple string array
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
        [itemArray addObject:s];
    }
    
    _itemGrid.dataSource = self;
    _itemGrid.delegate = self;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return itemArray.count;
}

- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *c = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [c.customLabel setText:itemArray[indexPath.item]];
    return c;
}

@end
```

---

Now, in your Storyboard, add a `UIViewController` and assign its class to `BackPackController`

Assign the class of the cell Prototype to `CollectionViewCell`, and set its Identifier to "cell1" (without the quotes).

Add a `UICollectionView` and constrain it with 20-points on all 4 sides. Give it and its default cell contrasting background colors so we can see it.

Add a `UILabel` to the cell prototype, and constrain it centered.

Connect the `IBOutlet UILabel *customLabel` to the label in the cell.

Connect the `IBOutlet UICollectionView *itemGrid` to the collection view in the controller.

Should look like this (ignore the other controllers I have in my storyboard):

[image]

When you run the app, you should see this:

[image]

Now you can start implementing your "PlayerItems" in UserDefaults, add your Search Bar, etc.